# Cramer-Rao bound in case of non-invertible Fisher Information matrix

Tags: estimation, fisher-information, singular-matrix

I am learning about the Cramer-Rao lower bound (CRLB) and Fisher Information matrix (FIM), and started trying to apply it to some simple toy models from physics. However, even for a simple example I run into a problem, which is that the Fisher Information matrix does not in general seem to be invertible. Hence my question is what we can say in this case, and whether the CRLB or some modified bound still exists in this case.

The toy model I am considering is a discrete model with PMF $p_X$ defined for $X \in \{ (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1) \}$:
\begin{equation}
\hspace{1cm} p_{1, 1} = p_{-1, -1} = \frac{1}{8} (2 + \tanh[J_{12}] + \tanh[J_{21}]), \\
\hspace{1cm} p_{-1, 1} = p_{1, -1} = \frac{1}{8} (2 - \tanh[J_{12}] - \tanh[J_{21}]) 
\end{equation}

The problem is to infer the parameters $J_{12}$ and $J_{21}$ from the PMF.
We can check that the regularity condition $E \left[ \frac{\partial \ln{p_X } }{\partial J_{ij}} \right] = 0 $ holds for both $J_{12}$ and $J_{21}$. Thus we can compute the FIM
\begin{align}
FIM &= \frac{1}{Z} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\text{sech}{(J_{12})}^4 &  \text{sech}{(J_{12})}^2 \text{sech}{(J_{21})}^2 \\ 
\text{sech}{(J_{12})}^2 \text{sech}{(J_{21})}^2 &  \text{sech}{(J_{21})}^4,
\end{pmatrix} \\
Z&=(2-\tanh{J_{12}} - \tanh{J_{21}})(2+\tanh{J_{12}}+\tanh{J_{21}}),
\end{align}
which we immediately identify as singular.

Now this is in fact a tricky example, because intuitively one already sees that we cannot infer these parameters separately but only in the combination $\tanh[J_{12}] + \tanh[J_{21}]$. However, we can still carry out the calculations and find a singular FIM. Now I'm trying to understand what this implies and whether one can still compute a lower bound on the variance of the parameters.

Comment: The singular Fisher information matrix just reflects the fact that the observed (and expected) log likelihood surface has the shape of a flat ridge (so one eigenvalue is zero).  This means that the model is unidentifiable.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the model is not fully identifiable as you say. However, using other approaches such as MLE we can still find a 1D subspace on which the model solutions should live (i.e. there is a solution of $J_{21}$ in terms of $J_{12}$ which gives max likelihood). Can we then still find some lower bound on how well we can identify this subspace from data?